# Python Numpy - Single neuron perceptron Weight Update Issue

Tags: python, numpy

I've been asked to program a perceptron for a programming assignment and am getting caught on the weight update. Specifically it messes up adjusting the 0th weight and this throws of the rest of the answer. Thank you for your help.

The code I have so far is.

```
import copy
def train(weights,inputs,targets,eta,nIterations):
    biasInputs = np.c_[np.ones((4,1)),inputs]
    print weights
    for n in range(nIterations): 
        activations = forward(inputs,weights)
        (rows,cols) = np.shape(biasInputs)
        # Here is where you update the weights using the learning parameter eta
        weights = np.add(weights, np.multiply(np.dot((np.subtract(targets,activations)), biasInputs) ,eta))
        # After you are done print the weights for verification purposes
        print weights

    return weights
```

The update equation I am working with is wi = wi + xi ( f(y) - f(y!))g

- w being the weights
- x being the inputs
- f(y) being the target(predicted) values
- f(y!) being the activation(actual) values
- and g being the learning factor(here eta)

The output when I run it is

```
Your output has 27 lines:
---
Line 1: Training for AND inputs
Line 2: [ 0.5 -0.25 0.6 ]
Line 3: [ 0.2 -0.35 0.5 ]
Line 4: [ -5.55111512e-17 -3.50000000e-01 4.00000000e-01]
Line 5: [-0.1 -0.35 0.3 ]
Line 6: [-0.1 -0.25 0.3 ]
Line 7: [-0.1 -0.15 0.3 ]
Line 8: [-0.2 -0.15 0.2 ]
Line 9: [-0.1 -0.05 0.3 ]
Line 10: [-0.2 -0.05 0.2 ]
Line 11: [-0.1 0.05 0.3 ]
Line 12: [-0.2 0.05 0.2 ]
Line 13: [-0.2 0.05 0.2 ]
Line 14: Training for XOR inputs
Line 15: [ 0.5 -0.25 0.6 ]
Line 16: [ 0.3 -0.35 0.5 ]
Line 17: [ 0.2 -0.35 0.4 ]
Line 18: [ 0.1 -0.35 0.3 ]
Line 19: [ -2.77555756e-17 -3.50000000e-01 2.00000000e-01]
Line 20: [ 0.1 -0.25 0.2 ]
Line 21: [ -2.77555756e-17 -2.50000000e-01 1.00000000e-01]
Line 22: [ 0.1 -0.15 0.1 ]
Line 23: [ -2.77555756e-17 -1.50000000e-01 2.77555756e-17]
Line 24: [ 0.2 -0.05 0.1 ]
Line 25: [ -2.77555756e-17 -1.50000000e-01 2.77555756e-17]
Line 26: [ -2.77555756e-17 -1.50000000e-01 2.77555756e-17]
Line 27: 


however the expected output is different. 

    Instructor output has 27 lines:
---
Line 1: This line is correct <
Line 2: This line is correct
Line 3: This line is correct
Line 4: [ 2.77555756e-17 -3.50000000e-01 4.00000000e-01]
Line 5: [-0.2 -0.35 0.3 ]
Line 6: [-0.2 -0.25 0.3 ]
Line 7: [-0.2 -0.15 0.3 ]
Line 8: [-0.2 -0.05 0.3 ]
Line 9: [-0.3 -0.05 0.2 ]
Line 10: [-0.2 0.05 0.3 ]
Line 11: [-0.3 0.05 0.2 ]
Line 12: [-0.2 0.15 0.3 ]
Line 13: [-0.2 0.15 0.3 ]
Line 14: This line is correct
Line 15: This line is correct
Line 16: This line is correct
Line 17: This line is correct
Line 18: This line is correct
Line 19: [ 2.77555756e-17 -3.50000000e-01 2.00000000e-01]
Line 20: [ 2.77555756e-17 -2.50000000e-01 2.00000000e-01]
Line 21: [ 2.77555756e-17 -1.50000000e-01 2.00000000e-01]
Line 22: [-0.1 -0.15 0.1 ]
Line 23: [ 2.77555756e-17 -5.00000000e-02 1.00000000e-01]
Line 24: [ -1.00000000e-01 -5.00000000e-02 2.77555756e-17]
Line 25: [ 0.1 0.05 0.1 ]
Line 26: [ 0.1 0.05 0.1 ]
Line 27: This line is correct
```

Comment: The weight update you have there is of the form (new weight) = (old weight) + (weight update), where (weight update) = (small constant) (gradient wrt weights). My advice to debugging this is to break the formula into pieces: compute the update and print it before combining it to produce the new weights, and print out the gradient. You can check the gradient by computing a numerical approximation such as (grad output wrt weights) = (output(w + delta w) - output(w))/(delta w), where (delta w) is a small increment. Also, try noisy data instead of perfect "and" or "xor" data.

Comment: FYI: if you're dealing with numpy ndarrays you can use `a + b`, `a * b`, `a - b` etc. rather than `np.add(a, b)`, `np.multiply(a, b)`, `np.subtract(a, b)` etc. It would make your code much easier to read (and debug).